# 'unauthorized user' reponse from philips-hue bridge

Tags: philips-hue, iotivity

Now I'm trying to control Hue bridge with IoTivity framework.

When I send GET message from MPMClientSample (MiniPluginManager)
response message was

```
[{
    "error": {
        "type": 1,
        "address": "/lights",
        "description": "unauthorized user"
    }
}]
```

What should I use 'username' for this?
Now I'm using 'newdeveloper' as default value.

Comment: hi alexlee, have you checked the documentation for anything related to authentication? as the message as it is, it looked like your request is not authenticated. the documentation unfortunatelly [walled](https://developers.meethue.com/login/?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.meethue.com%2Fdevelop%2Fget-started-2%2F), sorry cant provide much help. anyhow, please provide some example code how you do the request to help people helping you. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
https://developers.meethue.com/develop/get-started-2/

refer the document from developers page.
I could get generated username from hue bridge.

'We need to use the randomly generated username that the bridge creates for you. Fill in the info below and press the POST button.'

'When you press the POST button you should get back an error message letting you know that you have to press the link button. This is our security step so that only apps you want to control your lights can. By pressing the button we prove that the user has physical access to the bridge.'

'Go and press the button on the bridge and then press the POST button again and you should get a success response like below.'